# Activating/Deactivating worker roles when using traffic manager in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm currently deploying Traffic manager in front of our Cloud services in order to support a failover scenario.

My question is: How could I support having worker roles in a "deactivated" and "activated" state, depending on the traffic managers traffic redirection?

We have Cloud services in North Europe and I want a failover setup in West Europe. However I don't want the worker roles to hit the SQL and data located in North Europe (queues, SQL, etc), before the Traffic manager points traffic to West Europe.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Which worker roles (NE or WE) you don't want to hit the database in NE?

Comment: Basically all roles not pointed to by the traffic manager..
When the traffic starts hitting my WE datacenter, I would like for all roles in WE to hit "play", but otherwise stay in a "pause" state.
Makes sense?